# TableLayout fills parent

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to add a TabeLayout to a LinearLayout programmatically.
This is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/content">
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is how i add the table in my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
        String[] content = new String[] {"Hello", "World", "Test"};

        float d = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int dp = (int)(3*d);
        TableLayout.LayoutParams tableParams =
                new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        TableRow.LayoutParams rowParams =
                new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        TableLayout table = new TableLayout(this);
        table.setLayoutParams(tableParams);
        for(int i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            row.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
            int length = content[i].length();
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
            textView.setText(content[i]);
            textView.setPadding(dp, 0, dp, 0);
            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            row.addView(textView);
            table.addView(row);
        }
        table.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        linearLayout.addView(table);
    }


}
```

as you can see the tableParams are set to wrap_content. However, when i set the background color of the table i see, that the width of the table is as long as the display. Why is that so and how can i change that?

This is the output:
http://postimg.org/image/e29bsg9vv/

Comment: What happens if you have only 1 textView added? Does it take up the entire row?

Comment: Not even the row takes up the entire width, only the table.
I've created a minimalistic app with different bckgroundColors for the rows and the table. See my edited post. I get the same output when i set the BackgroundColor of the TextViews instead of the rows

Answer (score 0):

TableLayout deals with width a bit differently.
You need to let the TableLayout know that it can shrink the columns.
Try:

```
table.setShrinkAllColumns(true);
```

Take a look at the reference docs for [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html). In particular, notice it states the following:

> The total width of the table is defined by its parent container.

---

Also, as a tip, you can replace:

```
table.setLayoutParams(tableParams);
linearLayout.addView(table);
```

with:

```
linearLayout.addView(table, tableParams);
```

Comment: "The total width of the table is defined by its parent container"